# Cropping a Bitmap to 1:1 Aspect Ratio

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, system.drawing

I have Bitmaps with an aspect ratios like the following or may be in any aspect ratio..

[image]

[image]

When the user specifies an option i need a way to crop out the surrounding portions from these images so that an Image with 1:1 Aspect ratio is produced.
Like this

[image]

I think i will take the center point in these images and crop out the sides..

I have found this method in the web platform.. but Bitmap does not have a `Crop`method

```
 public static WebImage BestUsabilityCrop(WebImage image, decimal targetRatio)
        {
            decimal currentImageRatio = image.Width / (decimal)image.Height;
            int difference;

            //image is wider than targeted
            if (currentImageRatio > targetRatio)
            {
                int targetWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(targetRatio * image.Height));
                difference = image.Width - targetWidth;
                int left = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(difference / (decimal)2));
                int right = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(difference / (decimal)2));
                image.Crop(0, left, 0, right);
            }
            //image is higher than targeted
            else if (currentImageRatio < targetRatio)
            {
                int targetHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(image.Width / targetRatio));
                difference = image.Height - targetHeight;
                int top = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(difference / (decimal)2));
                int bottom = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(difference / (decimal)2));
                image.Crop(top, 0, bottom, 0);
            }
            return image;
        }
```

Please advice a way to tackle this issue.

Comment: There is a DrawImage overload that takes a source rectangle. Use this to draw into a suitable target bitmap!

Comment: Are you asking for converting image rectangle to square?

Comment: @IvanStoev yeah.. kind of

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494403/crop-image-to-43-aspect-ratio-c-sharp?rq=1) is an example of cropping, you can adjust it for your needs..

Comment: @IvanStoev That method throws some exception and crashes the process when aspect ratio is set to 1:1.

Comment: I meant something similar. If you wish, define the expected method signature and I (or someone else) will post you a possible implementation.

Comment: @IvanStoev  
Thanks.. but what do you mean by signature..?

Comment: Something like `public static Image Crop(Image source, {other params})`

Comment: @IvanStoev `Bitmap Crop(Bitmap source)` the aspect ratio can be hardcoded .. rather than passing parameters .. i just need a way to crop the image to a square..(1:1).

Comment: @IvanStoev Also i need to do this by cutting the image from the bottom.. only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
public static Image Crop(Image source)
{
    if (source.Width == source.Height) return source;
    int size = Math.Min(source.Width, source.Height);
    var sourceRect = new Rectangle((source.Width - size) / 2, (source.Height - size) / 2, size, size);
    var cropped = new Bitmap(size, size);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(cropped))
        g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    return cropped;
}
```

This does cropping from the center. If you want to crop from bottom/right, then just use `var sourceRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, size, size);`.

Comment: Thanks :).............

Comment: This just solved my problem. Thanks!